# rails - collection_select selected value if defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true, :selected => 2 %>
```

Problem is I only want the selected value of 2 if the value @permission.role_id is nil.

so I tried:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true, {:selected => 2 if @permission.role_id.nil?} %>
```

but that made Rails angry. How can I make a condition selected value based on if a separate variable is nil or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ok I guess I'll feel stupid in 2 mins, but what about

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, prompt: true, @permission.role_id ? {} : {selected: 2 } %>
```

The reason why your solution is not working is that your `if` can return `nil`, therefor looking something like that:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true, {nil} %>
```

Where `{nil}` is syntax error

Answer (score 13):

While the accepted solution with the ternary operator works, I don't think it is quite as readable as the following solution:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true, :selected => @permission.role_id || 2 %>
```

Comment: this seems to fail with a nil error if the object attribute is nil

Comment: try wrapping that last hash value in parentheses. Are you using a non-standard interpreter? :selected => (@permission.role_id || 2) thus, if role_id is nil it returns 2.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 3):

put this in your helper

```
def selected(permission)
  if permission.role_id.nil?
    return 2
  else
    .....
  end
end
```

and this in your view

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true, :selected => selected(@permission) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't have an if in that position. So a first solution, though a bit ugly, is something like the following:

```
<% if @permission.role_id.nil? %>
  <%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true, {:selected => 2} %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found @ecoologic's answer didn't work for me as ruby attempted to interpret the hash  as a key for a last argument instead of looking inside the hash for values.

The solution was to use a '[splat](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/fun-with-keyword-arguments/)'. However splats don't seem to work in that inline format, so I used the following:

```
<% selected = @permission.role_id ? {} : {selected: 2 } %>
<%= f.collection_select :role_id, roles, :id, :name, prompt: true, **selected %>
```